# How to pull a specific value from one dataframe into another?

Tags: pandas

I have two dataframes

[image]

How would one populate the values in bold from df1 into the column 'Value' in df2?

Comment: some sort of use of .mask or .loc .iloc ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `melt` on `df1` before `merge` your 2 dataframes

```
tmp = df1.melt('Rating', var_name='Category', value_name='Value2')
df2['Value'] = df2.merge(tmp, on=['Rating', 'Category'])['Value2']
print(df2)

# Output
    Category Rating  Value
0  Hospitals    A++    2.5
1  Education     AA    2.1
```

Comment: If I have Hospitals AA+

Comment: It doesn't matter. I made a typing error.The important thing is that the 2 values of the columns are the same

Comment: For some reason this code isn't quite working with a larger subset of data.. i.e. if I have in df1 Hospitals with these value under it for rows: AA + 2.5 ; AA 2.25 ; A 2.0 ; A- 2.5 there becomes a mismatch in df2

Comment: would it work better if the Categories were numbers instead of objects/letters?

Comment: df1.merge(df2.melt('Key',var_name='Severity'),on=['Severity','Key'])
 this solved it

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction!